# simple math homework table

Tags: tables, longtable

I would like to create a table that looks like this, but without any luck.

[image]

But the following code produces this (look below), and I got a problem in the last case that was larger than the one before it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|l|l|c|l|l|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Les Expressions}   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Polynôme ?} & $\rm{d^{\circ}}(P(x))$ & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Coef de monôme de degré}    \\ \cline{2-10} 
        & Oui            & Non            & 4                      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{3} \\ \hline
        $x^{6}+24x^{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{5}$ & Oui            & Non            & 4                      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{3} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but LaTeX tabular does not look good by default. You can get a better result if you make use of some package like booktabs or tabularray, for exmaple.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. (1) Do you want the LaTeX code in the tables as in the first image, or the equation as in the second one? (2) Do you maybe want the cells with 2 and 3 have the same width? (3) Why do you have 6 columns in your table definition for the "Coef de monôme de degré" part instead of just 2 columns?

Comment: @ I would like to have the cells with 2 and 3 have the same width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is very handy if you quickly want to draw a more customised table:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            width = \linewidth,
            stretch = 1.75,
            colspec = {X[4,c] *2{X[1,c]} X[5,c] *2{X[3,c]}},
            %%% More customised lines
            hline{1,Z} = {0.8pt},
            hline{3} = {0.5pt},
            hline{2} = {2-3}{0.3pt,rightpos=-1,endpos},
            hline{2} = {4}{0.3pt,leftpos=-1,rightpos=-1},
            hline{2} = {5-6}{0.3pt,leftpos=-1,endpos},
            %%% Alternatively just use regular lines
            % vlines,hlines,
            cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
            cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{},
            cell{1}{5} = {c=2}{},
        }
        Les Expressions & Polynôme ? & & $\rm{d^{\circ}}(P(x))$ & Coef de monôme de degré & \\
                        & Oui & Non & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
        $x^{6}+24x^{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{5}$ & Oui & Non & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
        $x^{6}+24x^{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{5}$ & Oui & Non & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
        $x^{6}+24x^{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{5}$ & Oui & Non & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want regular rules and bars with standard LaTeX, remove a part of the code with all lines starting from `hline{}...` and uncomment `vlines,hlines,`.

---

EDIT. Table with horizontal and vertical lines.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            width = \linewidth,
            stretch = 1.75,
            colspec = {X[4,c] *2{X[1,c]} X[5,c] *2{X[3,c]}},
            vlines, hlines,
            cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
            cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{},
            cell{1}{5} = {c=2}{},
        }
        Les Expressions & Polynôme ? & & $\rm{d^{\circ}}(P(x))$ & Coef de monôme de degré & \\
                        & Oui & Non & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
        $x^{6}+24x^{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{5}$ & Oui & Non & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
        $x^{6}+24x^{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{5}$ & Oui & Non & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
        $x^{6}+24x^{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{5}$ & Oui & Non & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with tabularray, could you please add vlines

Comment: If you prefer the table to look like in your screenshot, remove all instances of `hline{}...` and uncomment the code line with `vlines, hlines,`. Alternatively, if you prefer thicker horizontal rules, change only instances of `hline{2} ...` to this single line `hline{2} = {2-Z}{0.3pt},` and add only `vlines,`.

Comment: I see. I added code for a regular table. If you are not familiar with `tabularray`, have a look at the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray).